# How to replace '?' for a border?

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I have a `string` that stores different strings with the '?' in multiple different places:

Example 1

```
string question = "4 + ? = 7";
```

Example 2

```
string question = "5 + 5 = ?";
```

The `string` is then added to my `TextBlock`

```
question_txt.Text = question;
```

I want the '?' to be replaced with a border so it would be just a black outlined square where the '?' should be.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: it is not possible to border a character in a string. But if you are using a UI to show the string, like label or textblock, then its quite possible. 
and you have a string(!) that stores different strings(!!) ?? is it a string array?

Comment: @AbdurRahim Sorry I forgot that the string is then put into a `TextBlock` ill update my question

Comment: Replace `?` with `□`. (Copy the square from this text. It is the Black Square character)

Comment: are u using winform? or wpf?

Comment: Use the [White Square character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm)

Comment: Or white rectangle `▯` (U+25AF). Unicode will not work in all cases though.

Comment: I think, user will be able to replace '?' with the appropriate answer in the box / border?

Comment: @AbdurRahim In that case, a TextBox should suffice.

Comment: are you using this for captcha kinda thing ? you want to replace `?` with a textbox to enter the number ?

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla No, it's a game

Comment: @KTOV, then you can use `&#9744;` or Simply use two square brackets as [ ]

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla Would it then be possible to customize just the [] into a bolder font-family?

Comment: @KTOV, yes, if you are using `Label` or `Textblock` to show the text, add multiple `Run` in the content, they can have different font properties.

Comment: @KTOV, for example : `<TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="Address: " FontWeight="Bold"></Run>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding AddressLine1}"></Run>
                                        <Run Text=" | "></Run>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=AddressLine2}"></Run>
                                    </TextBlock>`

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla I don't feel that the `[]` gives the effect I want.. I've tried some of unicoded ones but none of them work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93580/discussion-between-shaminder-s-aujla-and-ktov).

Answer (score 1):

**The problem I understood:**

You are making a arithmatic game. Assume that Output will be like below.

1. An equation comes. Like 4 + ? = 7. OR 4 + 3 = ?
2. User will replace the '?' mark with appropriate answer.
3. If the Answer is correct, then it will go to the next question. there could be points or other strategies.

**In this case:**

You will have a list of questions, that's what you mentioned as string of string I think. And the program have to take each question, show to the user how you want to show (**? in textbox**).

So you have to find the **?** mark dynamically for each string and set it to a text box and other parts will be in one or two textblocks.

**Steps :**

1. Iterate through your collection of string. List can be.
2. foreach item, split by '?'
3. Then you will find 2 string in a string[], If only one '?' is in an equation.
4. if the second string is blank (`stringIsNullOrEmpty`) then assign the string[0] in textblock1 and assign "?" in textbox1.
5. If the second string is not null or empty then, assign string[0] in first label1, assign "?" in textbox1 and assign string[1] in label2.
  6.

You have to do it dynamically and invoke method for each submission of result.
From your question, it was not pretty clear, what you actually want to do. The answer is from my perception.

Comment: You've assumed that the user themselves will replace the '?' mark with the appropriate answer? How? I've just explained I only want a box displaying rather than the `?` mark.. Also, I explained that the `string` stores different strings, showing both examples of strings being stored so how did you get the idea that I was storing a string array ? :|

Comment: @KTOV your question is extremely unclear, which is already proven by the amount of discusison below it. Don't get annoyed with this user who at least tries to understand it.

Comment: as you are building a game, and there u show already two equation, so there should be more. If I am wrong, I am sorry. And if its not what you are trying, I will withdraw my answer.

Comment: @AbdurRahim It's fine dude, keep your answer though.. someone may find it useful if they have a similar problem like mine?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `IValueConverter` that returns `Panel` containing your string split into two and border between them.

So here's the code. 
First the converter that does most of the job.

```
public class StringToContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var question = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(question))
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        //Splitting question in each place where '?' char occurs
        var questionSplit = question.Split('?');
        var panel = GetPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < questionSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            //Add current part of the Question
            panel.Children.Add(GetTextBlock(questionSplit[i]));

            //If there's next part of your question black border is added to panel
            //That's usefull if you want to have more than one questionmark in your question
            if (i < questionSplit.Length - 1)
            {
                panel.Children.Add(GetBorder());
            }
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private Panel GetPanel()
    {
        var panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        return panel;
    }

    private TextBlock GetTextBlock(string text)
    {
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = text;

        return textBlock;
    }

    private Border GetBorder()
    {
        var border = new Border();
        var style = Application.Current.Resources["CustomBorderStyle"] as Style;
        border.Style = style;
        return border;
    }

    //Most likely you won't need converting back since you've got your question on the view model
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can see that `GetBorder()` reads style from resources (you can modify its style directly but I prefer external style, so just add this to `ResourceDictionary` your form is using (global resources in App.xaml will do the job too).

```
<Style x:Key="CustomBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Here's how to use it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
    <local:StringToContentConverter x:Key="StringToContent" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!-- 'Question' is the property in your DataContext -->
    <Label Content="{Binding Question, Converter={StaticResource StringToContent}}"/>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Provide an example and this could become a great answer.

Comment: Code added as requested.